# The alsa-restore service is not working

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, alsa

I am having trouble with sound on my Arch Linux system. When I reboot, my sound settings are incorrect. After logging in, if I run

```
sudo alsactl restore
```

then everything is fine. I was under the impression that the `alsa-restore` systemd service is supposed to take care of this

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service
#
# Note that two different ALSA card state management schemes exist and they
# can be switched using a file exist check - /etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf .
#

[Unit]
Description=Save/Restore Sound Card State
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/alsa/state-daemon.conf
ConditionPathExistsGlob=/dev/snd/control*

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/alsactl restore
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/alsactl store
```

The service seems to be active and running

```
$ sudo systemctl status alsa-restore
● alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static; vendor preset: disabl
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2017-11-30 11:55:58 EST; 5min ago
  Process: 533 ExecStart=/usr/bin/alsactl restore (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 533 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/alsa-restore.service

Nov 30 11:55:58 cochlea systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Nov 30 11:55:58 cochlea systemd[1]: Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
```

What am I missing? How do I get my sound setting to be restored at login?

Comment: For posterity, I ran into this on an Ubuntu 18 machine and took the timer approach from this thread: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1504404